# jQuery if element is next and has class?

Tags: jquery

Im using this to toggle the visibility of an element:

```
$(".trigger").click(function() {
    $(this).next().slideToggle();
});
```

```html
<p class="triggger">Trigger</p>
<p class="target">this is the target</p>
```

Its working fun but I want to make it so the next element is only toggled if it has a class of target. The following isnt working:

```
$(this).next().hasClass("target").slideToggle();
```

Comment: The reason this is not working is because `.hasClass()` returns a `boolean` value and not the object with the class.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

this will do the trick:

```
$(this).next(".target").slideToggle();
```

---

`.slideToggle()` will only be fired on next element if that has a className of `target` only.

Answer (score 2):

The function hasClass('target') returns a boolean..So instead change your function to the following.

```
$(".trigger").click(function() {
    if($(this).next().hasClass('target')) { $(this).next().slideToggle(); }
});
```

Regards.

Answer (score 1):

Jquery [`.next()`](http://api.jquery.com/next/), support selector(`.next([selector ])`).

Try This :

```
$(".trigger").click(function() {
    $(this).next(".target").slideToggle();
});
```

> `$(this).next(".target")` - will select the very next sibling of each elements with trigger class. Keep only the ones with a class "target".

**[Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/KLp7v/)**

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
if($(this).next().hasClass("target"))
{
       $(this).next().slideToggle();
}
```